# Expand all view-queries in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have queries like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM vwUsers
LEFT JOIN tblLocations
  ON vwUsers.id = tblLocations.owner
```

Is there an automated way to expand out this query to include the view statement (and any nested view statements)? I'd like to end up with something like:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT id,name,     -- vwUsers expanded into it's defining statement
     FROM tblUsers 
     LEFT JOIN tblNames 
     ON tblUsers.id = tblNames.id) AS vwUsers
LEFT JOIN tblLocations
ON vwUsers.id = tblLocations.owner
```

Comment: To what end? You are aware that this is almost exactly what the system will do before *optimizing* and *executing* the query, aren't you?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever :-O Wait, the system executes the query!?? ;) 
 I've inherited a database which has views nested to 7-8 levels (that I've found so far). I'm aware that the system will, as you put it, "_optimise_ and _execute_ the query", but there are some performance issues I'm investigating. An automated way to expand the nested views is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems clear:

1. Create a list with all refereed views
2. Get their definitions
3. Replace the definitions in your query

Something like this in my environment:

```
DECLARE @Objects TABLE
(
    [ObjectName] SYSNAME
   ,[Definition] NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO @Objects ([ObjectName])
VALUES ('[dbo].[SurveyInstancesHistory]')
      ,('dbo.vw_MystClients');

UPDATE @Objects
SET [Definition] = M.[definition]
FROM @Objects O
INNER JOIN [sys].[objects] OB
    ON OBJECT_ID([ObjectName]) =  OB.[object_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[sql_modules] M
    ON OBJECT_ID([ObjectName]) =  M.[object_id]
WHERE OB.[type] = 'V';

DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
SELECT *
FROM SurveyInstances SI
INNER JOIN [dbo].[SurveyInstancesHistory] SIH
    ON SI.[SurveyInstanceID] = SIH.[SurveyInstanceID]
INNER JOIN ProtoSurveys PS
    ON SI.[ProtoSurveyID] = PS.[ProtoSurveyID]
INNER JOIN dbo.vw_MystClients MC
    ON PS.[ClientID] = MC.[Client<br>ID];'


SELECT @DynamicTSQLStatement = REPLACE(@DynamicTSQLStatement,  [ObjectName], '(' + [Definition] + ') AS ' + [ObjectName])
FROM @Objects;

SELECT @DynamicTSQLStatement;
```

In order this to be automated the following cases must be handled:

- we can automatically get the referred objects using regex matches
- we can automatically replace the `CREATE VIEW .... AS` statement using regex

In you need a script that's always working in your example you need to write the regex expressions by yourself as people are creating views with different syntax. As the above can be used and edited by hand in order to run, a very complex script can be created depending on your needs.

Strongly recommenced to implement the [String Utility Functions Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878119.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in order to get regex support in T-SQL.